# Invision power board white space

Tags: php, xml, apache, centos, ipb

I have an established IPB setup at forum.bettercraft.net (You'll notice it's currently set to Offline), this is hosted with a hosting provider.  I'm moving it to a new domain as well as to my dedicated server, so it'll be at betterverse.net/forum

(I have already deactivated it for the previous domain)

However, when I transfer everything and connect it to the previous database, all I am seeing is white space - you can see this for yourself now.

IPB support says nothing is glaringly obviously wrong with my file setup, and that it must be a problem with my apache or php; but the "System Requirements" checker reports everything to be acceptable.

Apache logs, apparently, give nothing useful for support to look through.  Any ideas on where I would start on fixing httpd and/or php?

Comment: This site is for programming questions, not how to configure your server.

Comment: @MarcB At least try to be helpful. http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your file permissions to 755 via your FTP manager

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar issue. One of the things is to run the IPS Requirements Checker script , if it says everything is proper and then your'e still getting the White Screen, then it is the permission related issue.

You can do CHMOD 755 or if you're on VPS then chown -R apache.apache ips-dir/ will solve the issue.